# Why is my return value wrong?

Tags: c#, vector, casting, floating-point, double

I have a vector class in C# (a fragment below). My issue is that when I call GetMagnitude(), it always returns 0.0f - even with the debugger running and I check that Sq has a valid value, as soon as it gets passed back into other function (eg: Normalize() ), it has return 0.0f. Can someone explain this and help me fix it? My guess is that it has something to do with double->float conversion but I just can't figure it.

```
public class float3
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;


    public float GetMagnitude()
    {
        float SumSquares = (float)( Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2) + Math.Pow(z, 2));
        float Sq = (float)Math.Sqrt(SumSquares);
        return Sq;
    }

    public void Normalize()
    {
        float inverse = 1.0f / GetMagnitude();

        x *= inverse;
        y *= inverse;
        z *= inverse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever initialize x, y and z? In your example, it would obviously return 0.

Comment: you might want to consider writing x*x + y*y + z*z rather than using Math.Pow... it is both shorter and faster...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested your code with this set up and it worked perfectly:

```
void Main()
{
    var myData = new float3
    {
        x = 1,
        y = 1,
        z = 1
    };
    float result = myData.GetMagnitude();
}
```

I get the result 1.73...

Is it possible that the problem is elsewhere?  Could you create a small console app and insert that code just to isolate it?

Comment: How very embarrassing. Looks like you are right and my testing was not. Lesson learnt. Strip away *everything* else before claiming th code is wrong. My apologies and thankyou.